# Unable to map String to Object

Tags: java, jackson

I have a JSON value as follows in String format.

```
{
    "Sample": {
        "name": "some name",
        "key": "some key"
    },
    "Offering": {
        "offer": "some offer",
        "amount": 100
    }
}
```

Now if I try to map this as follows, it works and maps fine.

```
//mapper is ObjectMapper;
//data is the above json in String format
Map vo = mapper.readValue(data, Map.class);
```

But I want to map it to a custom Data class as follows.

```
Data vo = mapper.readValue(data, Data.class);
```

When I do this, the result of vo is null.

Refer to following on how the Data class is structured.

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Data {
    private Sample sample;
    private Offering offering;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Offering {
    public String offer;
    public int amount;
}

@Getter
@Setter
public class Sample {
    private String name;
    private String key;
}
```

Please advice what I am doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Does Jackson actually understand those `@Setter` and `@Getter` annotations?  Whenever I've done this I just created the appropriate methods.

Comment: I really doubt that vo is null. Its sample and its offering are probably null, though, since since Jackson would expect two properties named `sample` and `offering`, and the JSON contains `Sample` and `Offering`

Comment: I see in json its "Sample", but in class its 'sample'

Comment: @markspace - that's Lombok.  It's a way to generate getters and setters without having to write the getters and setters.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two options :

1. if you can change your `json` - you have to change `Sample` to `sample` and `Offering` to `offering`
2. Change your `Data` class to :

```
@Getter
@Setter
public class Data {
    @JsonProperty("Sample")
    private Sample sample;

    @JsonProperty("Offering")
    private Offering offering;
}
```

In the second option you have to tell `Jackson` what properties of your input `json` you want to map to which properties of your class, because by default it will try to map to lowercase properties names.

Answer (score 5):

There seems to be issue with Word Case here.
Its "Sample" in your json.
But its "sample" in java file.
Similarly for Offering.

You can of-course use @JsonProperty if you want to map without changing the case.

Answer (score 3):

It may be due to different mapping names of fields in json string and Demo model. "Sample" in json string but "sample" in model class.

You can use `@JsonProperty`

```
@JsonProperty("Sample")
private Sample sample;
@JsonProperty("Offering")
private Offering offering;
```